# Moq failed exception on Verify: Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

Here's another rookie noob question here:

Consider the following:

```
    public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName {get; set; }
    public string Address {get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository
{
    bool CreateDatabase(string name);
    bool UpdateTable(Company _co);
}

public class MyService
{
    private IRepository _repo;

    public MyService(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public bool Commit(string database_name, Company co)
    {
        if (_repo.CreateDatabase(database_name))
            return _repo.Commit(co);

        return false;
    }
}
```

So in the repository, if it was successful on creating the database, then it returns TRUE. Same goes for the UpdateTable if all SQL UPDATE was successful as well. Then all I'm doing is passing along the reults back to ViewModel to indicate that all went well.

So in my MSTest:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_If_Calls_CreateDatabase_And_UpdateTable()
    {
        var name = "test";
        var repoMock = new Mock<IRepository>();
        var _company = new Company();
        repoMock.Setup(r => r.CreateDatabase(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
        repoMock.Setup(r => r.UpdateCompanyTable(It.IsAny<Company>())).Returns(true);

        var engine = new MyService(repoMock.Object);

        var result = engine.Commit(name, _company);

        Assert.IsTrue(result);   // PASSES
        repoMock.Verify(r => r.CreateDatabase(name), Times.Once);           //FAILS
        repoMock.Verify(r => r.UpdateCompanyTable(_company), Times.Once);   //FAILS

    }
```

This is where things get so whacked. The result returns back true, which means that it got the proper results back, but the Moq verification fails and I get this exception:

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: r => r.CreateDatabase("test")

Why is that? Even if I remove Times.Once and just have `repoMock.Verify(r => CreateDatabase(name))` I still get the same failed error message.

Any suggestions?

### Corrections

The code really was the first suggested answer. but there was some copy and paste errors that crept in and this was due to the fact I was trying some variations to make the unit testing to work. For example, I've tried these variations:

```
engine.Commit(name, _company); // tried that first, that failed
engine.Commit(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Company>()); // failed too
engine.Commit(new String(), new Company()); // fails as well
engine.Commit(null, _company)); // fails!! GRR!!
engine.Commit(null, null)); // FAIL! *cocks gun* IT'S HAMMER TIME! *BANG!!*
```

I would have thought that the first line would have worked as someone suggested, but it didn't, hence why I am here asking for some help.

Comment: In myService.Commit method takes string as argument and you are passing an object of Company. Also while setting up expectation of repository.CreateDatabase you are ignoring value of database_name argument  but while verifying you are setting "test" as argument. Try putting `It.IsAny<string>()` while verifying.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, post your suggestion as an answer dude

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually, it was Chetan Ranpariya that came up with the answer in the comments, and I was hoping he would have posted a suggested answer instead of me so I could have given him the credit.

Because I'm using `It.IsAny<string>()` and `It.IsAny<Company>()`, I needed to have the SAME signature when trying to verify that the methods were indeed running once. Therefore, to test it out, it should have been this:

```
    repoMock.Verify(r => r.CreateDatabase(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once); 
    repoMock.Verify(r => r.UpdateCompanyTable(It.IsAny<Company>()), Times.Once);
```

NOW the test passes.

Thanks Chetan!

Comment: Whevever I need to run `Verify`, I always copy\paste the `Setup` line(s). Then just change "Setup" to "Verify". No conflicts that way ;)

Comment: That worked but I disagree that these two lines should be identical. Nothing wrong with your answer, but I logically feel that I should be able to setup my method to accept any primitive type and verify it received a specific type.